# jQuery all items between two classes

Tags: jquery, html

people can choose on a calendar the first and last day of their booking. 
Classes (.first) and (.last) will be added.

Example

```
<div class='date'>Monday</div> 
<div class='date first'>Tuesday</div> 
<div class='date'>Wednesday</div> 
<div class='date'>Thursday</div> 
<div class='date last'>Friday</div> 
<div class='date'>Saturday</div> 
<div class='date'>Sunday</div>
```

All days (between ".first" and ".last") should now get added the class ".choosen".

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
$('.first').nextUntil('.last').addClass('chosen')
```

If you need to include the first and last divs (you did say between, not including) you can use:

```
$('.first').nextUntil('.last').add('.first,.last').addClass('chosen')
```

Comment: @MathieuG - Obviously. Which is why I added the second snipped that does with `add()`. Note that the OP said *between* the first and last however.

Comment: Did not see the second snippet at first. You are right!

Answer (score 0):

There's maybe another way more efficient but you could do this :

```
$('.first').nextUntil('.last').addClass('choosen');
$('.last').addClass('choosen');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And what do I have to do if theres always a »<td>« around each div?

Comment: It should not bother that div are wraped with td. If you want the td to get the css class choosen, before addClass, add .parent() like $('.last').parent().addClass('choosen');

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) if you know the range of course.Take a look a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/cm6jq8tx/

```js
$("div").slice(2, 5).addClass('choosen');
```

```css
.choosen {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='date'>Monday</div>
<div class='date first'>Tuesday</div>
<div class='date'>Wednesday</div>
<div class='date'>Thursday</div>
<div class='date last'>Friday</div>
<div class='date'>Saturday</div>
<div class='date'>Sunday</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".first").nextUntil(".last").addClass('choosen');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".first ~ *:not(.last, .last ~ *)")
.addClass("choosen")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/qagsbwzu/